# extract information from GEO using rvest and selectorgadget, get error:"Error in class(out) <- "XMLNodeSet" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"

Tags: r, css-selectors, geo, rvest

I want to get the all the "Samples" IDs from [this link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE21610), I mean all the IDs like "GSM545657","GSM545658" ... .  I want to use the new package `rvest` to solve my problem, but I am not familiar with the CSS and xpath. I used the  [selectorgadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) to obtain the CSS selector.
I select the first ID:"GSM545657", it turned green, then I remove the informations that I do not want(they turned red). Now, all the Sample IDs are green or red. And the CSS selector shows like this:"tr:nth-child(23) .eye-protector-processed a" . My code was shown like this

```
Library(rvest);
myhtml<-html("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE21610");
myhtml %>% html_nodes("tr:nth-child(23) .eye-protector-processed a") %>%html_text()
```

and I gent the error *Error in class(out) <- "XMLNodeSet" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL* 
 If I just selct two IDs such as "GSM545665" and "GSM545666", I can use

```
myhtml %>% html_nodes("tr:nth-child(23) .eye-protector-processed a") %>%html_text()
```

And get the result, could you tell my the how to solve this problem, and suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the wrong selector. This works for me:

```
myhtml <- html("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE21610")
myhtml %>% 
  html_nodes("tr:nth-child(23) tr a") %>%
  html_text()
```

(but rvest should give a better error. I'll file a bug)

Comment: thank you very much, it really works. but I do not know the CSS selector well, so I use the selectorgadget tool, so how can I get the right result with selectorgadget. Do you have some suggentin to learn how to get the right css selctor pattern. Thank you again!

Comment: I used selector gadget to generate that selector.

Comment: thank you very much. I also used the selector gadget, but I do not understand why I get the wrong css selector. Can you tell my your procedure to get the right selector.